# Requisição ajax retorna decimais zerados do SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

Caros amigos, tenho uma aplicação Asp Net MVC5 que faz uso de ajax tanto nas inclusões como nos selects. A gravação dos valores decimais ocorre normalmente no banco SqlServer porém a recuperação me retorna zerada, embora a cultura esteja ajustada corretamente. Par a gravação uso essas duas funções

```
    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) ||
            !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
    }

    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
        range: function (value, element, param) {
            //Use the Globalization plugin to parse the value
            var val = Globalize.parseFloat(value);
            return this.optional(element) || (val >= param[0] && val <= param[1]);
        }
    });
```

Alguém ja passou por isso? Grato

Comment: Poderia por favor colocar o código do servidor?

Comment: Precisamos ver o código que gera a resposta (no controller) não o JS que faz a requisição